# Negative sentiment for text

Tags: sentence-structure

Could someone please explain why would the following text have negative sentiment? Is there any specific word or hidden semantics that makes it negative? Is completely subjective?

Text:

```
你那个城市十一银行还上班啊
```

Title:

```
【壕卡信用卡11-06】人生首卡，求卡神指教
```

Comment: questioner aware that 十一 looks like an abbreviation for the date of the Chinese national holiday 十一国庆节?

Comment: @user6065 I didn't know, but according to Google it is national day. Does presence of it in the text affect on the sentiment of the text?

Comment: 十一 here definitely means the Chinese national holiday. I'm not sure why it has negative sentiment, but it expresses a situation that is not supposed to  happen, because generally banks don't open on some holidays.

Comment: National Day holiday schedule for banks for 2014
http://www.cnrencai.com/zhichangzixun/86526.html
2014年国庆节银行放假安排：10月1日至7日放假调休，共7天。9月28日(星期日)、10月11日(星期六)上班。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative sentiment can be found in:
1.那个 
2. "还上班啊"
This is an exclamation sentence. The speaker who said it was kind of shocked because the person he/she was talking to have to deal with a situation that was supposed not to happen which is working during the national day.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new here and am a start-up teaching Chinese online. We use a different method called "decoding" and would love to use it here, too, because it makes things much easier to explain.

> 你   那个  城市    十一   银行    还   上班    啊?
>
> ni nage chengshi shiyi yinhang hai shangban a
>
> you that  city  Oct.1st Bank  still work (question)

I guess you know some Chinese. What might be confusing here is "shiyi" (ten one) means October 1st.

If you understand all elements with the right separation, it's quite easy to understand the logic in it.

Comment: it is very helpful, thanks a lot for laying this out!

Comment: the answer by @Duy Toan nails it, but you answer is very detailed. I would've marked both as answers if I could!

Comment: Hi, welcome, you don't need to sign you name in your post since it is automatically shown on the lower right corner.